# Context aware function

Tags: python

I have a piece of code below:

```
 // The only difference is grad
    class TestOne(...):
            def init(self):
                self.input_one = tr.allocate( ..., grad = False)
                self.input_two = tr.allocate( ..., grad = False)

        class TestTwo(...):
            def init(self):
                self.input_one = tr.allocate( ..., grad = True)
                self.input_two = tr.allocate( ..., grad = False)

        class TestThree(...):
            def init(self):
                self.input_one = tr.allocate( ..., grad = False)
                self.input_two = tr.allocate( ..., grad = True)


Test1 = TestOne()
Test2 = TestTwo()
Test3 = TestThree()

# definition of allocate. It is a wrapper of the PyTorch randn function 
# https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.randn
def allocate(..., grad):
    ...
    return torch.randn(..., require_grad=grad)
```

I want to reduce the duplicate code by implementing just one class but able to generate same objects as the code above.

```
class Test(...):
    // how to make it return different values? 
    def auto_set(self): 
        return False

    def init(self):
        self.input_one = tr.allocate( ..., grad = self.auto_set())
        self.input_two = tr.allocate( ..., grad = self.auto_set())

Test1 = Test()
# grad of input_one and input_two will be `False, False` 

Test2 = Test()
# grad of input_one and input_two will be `True, False` 

Test3 = Test()
# grad of input_one and input_two will be `False, True`
```

This is part of a big project, so I can't change the interface of the init function. There could be N number of inputs which would require N + 1 different classes. That is not a scalable implementation so want to find a solution to solve that.

PS: My previous question was causing too many confusions to others so I changed it hoping to clarify on what I really want to have.

Just posting my solution here:

```
class Test(object):
    init_counter = 0
    num_variable = 0
    def increase_init_counter(self):
        Test.init_counter += 1
        Test.auto_set_counter = 0

    def auto_set(self):
        if Test.init_counter == 0:
            Test.num_variable += 1
            return False
        else:
           print ("init_counter: {}, auto_set_counter: {}".format(Test.init_counter, Test.auto_set_counter))
           Test.auto_set_counter += 1
           if Test.init_counter == Test.auto_set_counter:
               return True
           else:
               return False

    def init(self):
        self.A = self.auto_set();
        self.B = False;
        self.C = self.auto_set();
        print ("A: {}, B: {}, C: {}".format(self.A, self.B, self.C))



=== Test

TestA = Test()
TestA.init()

for _ in range(TestA.num_variable):
  TestB = copy.deepcopy(TestA)
  TestB.increase_init_counter()
  TestB.init()
```

Comment: There's no way for the function to magically know how many variables there will be.  Something, somewhere will need to tell it that.

Comment: What determines how many variables there are?  Does it grow by 1 every time you call a particular function?  We need to know more of your system logic flow, more than you've shown here.

Comment: @NPE I thought I had read sth like that in an online book somewhere... I'll have to search... @Scott Hunter because `see` is called in a loop over range(3)...? However, the last output of _4_ lines isn't clear to me, too...

Comment: Anyway, what's the _actual_ problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Why do you call `test1()` 3 times in a loop? This isn't really being "context aware", more like "using `random.choice` multiple times"

Comment: Just modified my question to clarify on what I really want to have.

Comment: `tr` is undefined in your posted code, and `auto_set` is still identically `False`.  I'm still not clear on what "context" you mean.  Returning a different value with each call is usually done with a **generator**.  However, since you haven't used our suggestions of a list, we're not sure what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: In short, the naive version I have need to have three classes to generate test1/2/3. The version I am interested in just need one class to generate test1/2/3.

Comment: If you have a look at my answer, you'll see that this is possible to do. What I can show you there is a way how to get an indicator to differentiate between several instances of only one class. However, the algorithm _how_ this counter (in this case) can be transferred into your desired patterns of different True/False -pairs is up to you. (But at least the first three of my sample algorithm are congruent to what you posted as expected result... :-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see IIUYC...:

What you can do is to add a global, or let's say better *common* variable to the class definition, which is incremented when instanciating new objects of that class (and perhaps also better decremented when they are deleted).
This would give you the opportunity to implement different behaviuors of `__init__()` depending on the number of objects already created before.

Imagine a test class like

```
class Test():
    i = 0
    def __init__(self):
        Test.i += 1
    def __del__(self):
        Test.i -= 1
```

After creating a first object, the common counter is `1`:

```
t1 = Test()

t1.i
1
```

After creating a second object, the common counter is `2`:

```
t2 = Test()

t2.i
Out: 2
```

... in all existing objects, because it's a common counter:

```
t1.i
Out: 2
```

---

Some sample implementation of what I think you want to achieve:

```
class Test():
    i = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.A = bin(Test.i)[-1] == '1'
        self.B = bin(Test.i)[-2] == '1'
        Test.i += 1
    def __del__(self):
        Test.i -= 1

t1 = Test()
print(t1.i, t1.A, t1.B)
# 1 False False

t2 = Test()
print(t2.i, t2.A, t2.B)
# 2 True False

t3 = Test()
print(t3.i, t3.A, t3.B)
# 3 False True
```

Answer (score 3):

If you find yourself using numbered variable names (e.g. `v1`, `v2`, `v3`) you need to stop immediately and think *"Should I use a list instead?"* - and the answer is "yes" in almost all cases.

Other notes:

- To pick random values, make a list of possible values (in this case, `[True, False]`) and use `random.choice()`
- `range()` can make a list of N values, which we can use to make another list of random choices (see "list comprehension" when you don't understand the `[x for x in iterable]` syntax).
- Classes have `__init__` as the constructor, you don't need a manual `init` function.
- Classes should use a capital letter at the start of their name.

Code:

```
from random import choice

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, num_values): 
        self.values = [choice([True, False]) for _ in range(num_values)]

    def see(self):
        print(self.values)

for _ in range(3):
    test1 = Test(3)
    test1.see()
```

prints something like:

```
[False, False, False]
[True, False, True]
[True, True, False]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My previous question doesn't capture what I really want to have so it caused confusions to you. Could you please take a look at the modified question and see if you have any feedback?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suspect that what you need is a `list` of instance attributes (the variables in each object of the type).

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.v = []

    # how to make it return different values? 
    def auto_set(self): 
        return False

    def init(self):
        self.v.append(self.auto_set())

    def see(self):
        print (self.v)

for _ in range(3): 
    test1 = test()
    test1.init()
    test1.see()
```

This will allow you to add to the attribute list.  Is that enough to get you moving?  We can't suggest a more thorough solution until you explain your system better.

Comment: Could you take a look at the modified question? Sorry for the confusion.